# Problem with missing values in a factor variable

Tags: r, density-plot

I have a data set on almost 3,000 harvested animals, and I am trying to make some density plots on lengths and weights grouped by sex. The SEX variable is a factor variable. The problem is that there are missing sex determination for a few of these animals, and I run into all kinds of problems, and it seems as if most problems has to do with these missing values.

My data frame is called CATCH, and after reading the data, I classed the SEX variable as factor:

```
catch$SEX <- as.factor(as.character(catch$SEX))
```

Making a basic density plot for all the data works well

```
ggplot(catch, aes(x = LENGTH)) +
  geom_density(color="black",fill="lightblue")
```

but I get the warning that "Removed 23 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density)", which I assume are the missing values.

When making similar plots grouped by sex

```
ggplot(catch, aes(x = LENGTH,y=..count..,fill=SEX)) +
  geom_density() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#868686FF", "#EFC000FF","#f6f6f6f6")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#868686FF", "#EFC000FF","#E6E6E6E6"))
```

I get the exact same warning, but, the NA's has not been omitted. There is a separate graph for the NA's and they are consequently a part of the legend:

[image]

How do I correctly declare the missing values for the factor variable SEX, and how do I omit them from the analyses?

Answer (score 1):

You could try filtering the `NAs` before plotting using the `tidyverse` packages

```r
library(tidyverse)
catch %>%
   filter(!is.na(SEX)) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = LENGTH,y=..count..,fill=SEX)) +
     geom_density() +
     scale_color_manual(values = c("#868686FF", "#EFC000FF","#f6f6f6f6")) +
     scale_fill_manual(values = c("#868686FF", "#EFC000FF","#E6E6E6E6"))
```

Comment: Error message: "Could not find function %>%"